# How to get line separator for SQL in a generic manner?

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there a way to get a sql-environment line separator? I guess that it is not equivalent of

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

And even if it's true for some of the DB, it's not guaranteed that it will always stay like that....

Comment: The line separator for SQL is irrelevant. I have never seen a DBMS that actually cares about that. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I second @a_horse_with_no_name's comment. With the [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) integration tests, we didn't run into any issues when using `\n` as a line separator in 17 popular RDBMS...

Comment: @LukasEder Well, I still haven't encounter any problem, but I thought that problem might occur when changing DB, so I was looking for a generic way, like System.getProperty("line.separator");.

Comment: Chances you will run into around 100 other compatibility issues before this one are high, believe me :-) What databases are you planning to support?

Comment: @LukasEder I write an app that should be completely generic, since it should meet coustmer requirements...

Comment: @Alaychem: I wouldn't do all that work yourself, if I were you. [Hibernate / JPA](http://hibernate.org/) does a great job if you don't really need SQL. [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) is a great choice, if you really need SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no default line separator system like `line.separator`, however you can create one yourself (say `sql.line.separator`) and populate it in the command line

```
java -Dsql.line.separator=...
```

When have you noticed the need? most databases accept `;` as command separator and ususally this is what you need.

Comment: I would take the first line of your answer as answer ('the answer is no'), the rest is not what I was looking for...